# Drawing lines duplicate when I try to export the PDF from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have 3 subreprots(added to solution as embedded resources), and I want to export them from VS2010, but when I do that, I am getting some lines which I drew and then deleted them. So basically, I drew a line in footer subreport, deleted it and again drew a new one, but when I export the report, I am getting two lines, the "deleted" and the new one.

Has anyone see something like this before?

Comment: 1)You should probably restart your box or try it on a diff PC. 
2)See if it happens there but first make sure that only 1 line exists.
3) Create your report from scratch and see if it happens
Also what do you mean by " I have 3 subreprots(added to solution as embedded resources)", dont quite understand that.

Comment: Hi, I made it from scratch and everything works. I thought that it might have something to do with the Build Action. That report was in mess anyway. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Do  you want to post that as your answer.

Comment: Well, not really, it was not a real answer, I made it from scratch. ;)

Comment: Well that is one answer for someone who is stuck in the same situation as you were. Better than no answer.